# checking if given vector contains already elements of pair in c++

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

let us suppose have following pairs

```
0 -1 
0 -2 
0 -3 
1- 2
2 -3
3- 4
2 -4
4- 5
5 -6
```

i would like to insert  those pairs into vector , so that i  should have each element only one times , for instance
start with empty  vector :

0-1  is inserted 
now we are checking 0-2  , there exist 0, but not 2, so 0-2 is inserted, we have

```
0-1
0-2
```

now  0-3 , 3  is not in the list, so we can insert

```
0-1 
0-2
0-3
```

now  lets us consider 1-2 , of course we have   both of them , so skip, now let us consider 2-3, again we can skip, 3-4 , 3 exist but not  4, so we can insert
3-4 ,  after inserting of 4 ,  4 also exist,so reject 2-4  then comes  4-5 and 5-6, so we have following list

```
0-1 
0-2
0-3
3-4 
4-5
5-6
```

i have following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct edge
{
    int a, c;
    float weight;//edge  a-c  has weight
    bool operator() (edge x, edge y)
    {
        x.weight < y.weight;

    }
};
int noncyclical_sum(vector<edge>s)
{
    int total = 0;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>  b;
    auto m = make_pair(s[0].a, s[0].c);
    b.push_back(m);
    total = total + s[0].weight;
    vector<edge>::iterator it;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        auto m = make_pair(s[i].a, s[i].c);
        //if (find(b.begin(), b.end(), s[i].a) != b.end() && find(b.begin(), b.end(), s[i].c) != b.end())

            if (find(b.begin(), b.end(), m.first) != b.end() && find(b.begin(), b.end(), m.second) != b.end())
            {
            continue; //both element is in the  vector
        }
                else
        {

            b.push_back(m);
            total = total + s[i].weight;
                    }

        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator ii;
        for (ii = b.begin(); ii != b.end(); ii++)
            cout << ii->first << "  " << ii->second;

            }

}
int main()
{



    return 0;
}
```

at first time , i have pushed  first pair, starting from the second one, i am checking  if at the same time both element is in vector,  i am rejecting pairs and continue, otherwise i push new  pairs and continuing , but i  have following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::pair<int,int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  kurskal_algorithm   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xutility   3161
```

what is wrong ? thanks in advance

Comment: Your `bool operator()` is bugged: no value is returned.

Comment: not this one,  that is not problem  i think

Comment: I don't see you including `<utility>` where `std::pair` (with all of the comparison operators) is defined.

Comment: i have added thanks in advance for pointing about this

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
if (find(b.begin(), b.end(), m.first) != b.end() && find(b.begin(), b.end(), m.second) != b.end())
```

Let's check the arguments of `std::find` call: `b.begin()` and `b.end()` are `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator`s while `m.first` is `int`.

So, you're trying to find `int` in the `vector` of `pair`s. You can't do that.

Also, all of your functions lack the required `return` statements.

Comment: i have added  return  statement to  both function, just only one error

Comment: @datodatuashvili You should change the way you store data. To look for an `int` in the set of all `int`s, you need a `std::vector<int>` which stores them.

Comment: i will use  additional array